Color code intensity of tile using row percentages in plot_confusion_matrix from cvms
I made a confusion matrix with cvms plot_confusion_matrix in R. I would like the color intensity of each tile represent the row percentage instead of the counts. In plot_confusion_matrix you can change the color intensity using the intensity_by option. However, row percentages can not be used here. Are there any other options how to solve this? If not is it possible to recreate this plot in ggplot in such a way that it is (almost) similar with rowpercentages as color intensity?
I have made the following dummy code:
library(tidyverse)
library(cvms)
data(iris)

# Create a new categorical variable with 4 classes
set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
new_factor <- factor(sample(c("Class1", "Class2", "Class3", "Class4"), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE))

# Add this new categorical variable to the iris dataset
iris_new <- cbind(iris, New_Categorical_Var = new_factor)

subs_all <- iris_new %>%  select(Species, New_Categorical_Var)
subs_all$Species <- factor(subs_all$Species)
subs_all$New_Categorical_Var <- factor(subs_all$New_Categorical_Var)


tbl_all <- table(subs_all)
cfm_all <- as.tibble(tbl_all)

plot_confusion_matrix(cfm_all, 
                      target_col = "Species" , 
                      prediction_col = "New_Categorical_Var" ,
                      counts_col = "n")

